# How to solve SocketTimeoutException in ionic 3

Tags: sockets, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Problem**.

Get a connection error as below in the ionic 3 in HTTP post API call.

**Error in detail**.

`{"status":-4,"error":"Request timed out:java.net.SocketTimeoutException:timeout}`

Answer (score 1):

`this.http.setRequestTimeout(300);`//Time is in seconds here it is 5 minutes you can adjust it.

Add this code before the HTTP post request. This solved my problem.